# Display Value from Sub Query in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, inner-join, lateral-join

I need to display the value MIN(pa.DataAdjudicacao) in the SELECT.
And how can I replace this Subquery for a Join?
How can I do it?
As far as I have searched I haven't found any way to do it.
Please help.

```
SELECT p.id, p.referencia
FROM PCTSproposta p
WHERE p.ID in (SELECT pa.Proposta
            FROM PropostaAdjudicada pa
            WHERE pa.Proposta = p.ID
            GROUP BY pa.Proposta
            HAVING MIN(pa.DataAdjudicacao) >= '2020-10-01' And MIN(pa.DataAdjudicacao) <= '2020-10-31')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is overcomplicated.
You use subquery to filter the data by `IN` predicate, but select the same `ID` that you've passed into filter of subquery. So your `IN` looks like `EXISTS`.
But if you need that min, you should use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.id,
  p.referencia,
  pa2.DataAdjudicacao
FROM PCTSproposta p
  JOIN (
    SELECT pa.Proposta,
      MIN(pa.DataAdjudicacao) as DataAdjudicacao
    FROM PropostaAdjudicada pa
    GROUP BY pa.Proposta
    HAVING MIN(pa.DataAdjudicacao) BETWEEN date '2020-10-01'AND date '2020-10-31'
  ) pa2
    on pa2.Proposta = p.ID
```

Depending on roles of the `Id` column (if it is primary key of `PCTSproposta`), data integrity and cardinality the subquery can be merged into main query:

```
SELECT p.id,
  p.referencia,
  MIN(pa.DataAdjudicacao) as DataAdjudicacao
FROM PCTSproposta p
  JOIN PropostaAdjudicada pa
    on pa2.Proposta = p.ID
GROUP BY p.id,
  p.referencia
HAVING MIN(pa.DataAdjudicacao) BETWEEN date '2020-10-01'AND date '2020-10-31'
```

Comment: I really like this solution, but I have to put the select columns in the group by (I mean columns from PCTSproposta)

Comment: I will take your first option, seems the best to me, thanks a lot, learnt with this

Comment: @JSantos.PCTS I've updated my code. But it really depends. If, for example, you have 10 rows in `PCTSproposta` that select 100 corresponding (not grouped) rows from `PropostaAdjudicada` out of 100000 overall rows in that table, then it can make sence. I didn't tested the query plan to check if Oracle will push filter on `Proposta` column into the subquery before the arrgegation. In such case athe GMB's lateral join version can also be more performant (and use index acess for example).

Comment: Well I have over 5000 rows in PCTSproposta and almost a 1000 in PropostaAdjudicada so I think any of this will perform good, or not?

Answer (score 0):

A lateral join comes to mind:

```
SELECT p.id, p.referencia, pa.*
FROM PCTSproposta p
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT MIN(pa.DataAdjudicacao) minDataAdjudicacao
    FROM PropostaAdjudicada pa
    WHERE pa.Proposta = p.ID
) pa
WHERE pa.minDataAdjudicacao >= '20201001' AND pa.minDataAdjudicacao < '20201101'
```